# Correcting column value ordering in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got the following dataframe:

```
    state   state_abbr fips   pop       cases   deaths      percent_cases    total_starbucks
1   Alabama     AK      1    4903185    7888      290        0.16087502           28
2   Alaska      AL      2    731545     366       7          0.05003110           52
3   Arizona     AZ      4    7278717    8640      362        0.11870224           267
4   Arkansas    CA      5    3017804    3431      76         0.11369194           2131
5   California  CO      6    39512223   55072     2235       0.13937965           350
6   Colorado    DC      8    5758736    16527     840        0.28699006           65
7   Connecticut DE      9    3565287    29287     2436       0.82144860           16
8   Delaware    FL      10   973764     5208      177        0.53483185           438
9   District of Columbia GA 11  705749  5016      251        0.71073427           189
10  Florida     HI      12   21477737   36070     1378       0.16794134           58
```

So on and so forth down the list. However, if you notice, the `state_abbr` and `state` columns aren't ordered the same way, which screws up the rest of the dataframe. The `state_abbr` values for AR, CT, and ID are placed at the end of the list, after Wyoming, for some reason. I'd like to know how to correct this, whether it be by manually changing it, fixing it via one line of code, or whatever. I don't particularly care how pretty the code is, as long as it works.

Here's my r code, for reference. It's also not very pretty, but I just want it all to work before I make it pretty.

```
starbucks_loc <- read.csv("starbucks_us_locations.csv", header = FALSE)
corona_states <- read.csv("us-states.csv")
state_pops <- read.csv("nst-est2019-alldata.csv")

pops_df <- state_pops %>%
  filter(SUMLEV == "40") %>%
  rename(pop = POPESTIMATE2019) %>%
  rename(state = NAME) %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(pop)

starbs_df <- starbucks_loc %>%
  rename(latitude = V1, longitude = V2, state_abbr = V3, address = V4) %>%
  mutate(state_abbr = str_extract(state_abbr, "(?<=- )[A-Z]{2}(?= -)")) %>% 
  count(state_abbr) %>%
  rename(total_starbucks = n) %>% 
  drop_na() %>%
  add_column(fips = 1:36)

corona_df <- corona_states %>%
  filter(date == "2020-05-03") %>%
  filter(state != "Puerto Rico") %>%
  group_by(state, fips) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(cases, deaths), sum) %>% 
  full_join(pops_df) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(percent_cases = (cases / pop) * 100) %>%
  left_join(starbs_df[,c("fips", "state_abbr")]) %>% 
  full_join(starbs_df) %>%
  select(state, state_abbr, fips, pop, cases, deaths, percent_cases, total_starbucks)
```

The `add_column(fips = 1:36)` line is there because the .csv with the starbucks locations only went up to Ohio, so I needed to add that column in order to join that dataframe with the `corona_df` dataframe.

Comment: `dplyr` is part of the `tidyverse`. Could you make your example as minimal as possible?

Comment: Do you want to change the `state_abbr` to match the `state` column or vice versa? I.e., which one do you think is right?

Comment: Also, I think the root of your problem might be a lack of DC---notice in the data you show that states go Delaware, District of Columbia, Florida, and the abbreviations go DE, FL, GA

Comment: @Gregor Thomas I'd like `state_abbr` to match the `state` column, ideally. As for the lack of DC -- it's there, but, for some reason, the `state_abbr` column bumped AR down to the bottom of the list, rather than include it, as well as the lack of cohesive ordering.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, now I see it. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a look-up table, which you can do with built-in variables `state.name` and `state.abb`, delete the column you don't trust from your data, and join to the look-up table.

Something like this:

```
state_lookup = data.frame(state = c(state.name, "District of Columbia"), state_abbr = c(state.abbr, "DC"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

corona_df = corona_df %>% 
  select(-state_abbr) %>%
  left_join(state_lookup)
```

I'd encourage you to track down where this error was introduced and fix it at the source, otherwise some of your data may already be wrong.

Comment: With regards to manually editing where the error is: how would I go about that? I suspect it's in my `starbs_df` dataframe, so I'd like to go in and manually change some of the data, whether that be manually reordering the `state_abbr` codes and then joining, or doing something else.

Comment: I wouldn't change it manually--I'd change it programmatically. This answer shows one possibility for doing that. I would just make sure to change it as far upstream in your data process as possible.

Comment: I actually figured it out. I forgot r has its own functions for state names and abbreviations, which your answer helped me remember. I added a dataframe of all 50 states and D.C. and their abbreviations, then left joined it to starbs_df, then full joined it to my corona_df dataframe, and it worked like a charm.